# How can I make SharePoint Online Search Managed Property behave consistently?

Tags: document-library, search-results, managed-property

Our SharePoint site has a document library with a custom column of data called "ArticleID" and we've made it queryable and searchable and everything, but the results are strangely inconsistent.

Like I get nothing when searching "45-72-31"
[image: search 45-72-31]

But I see a result when querying "articleid:45-72-31"
[image]

But almost the opposite happens when I get fewer results querying "articleid:123"
[image]

Than I do when I just search for "123"
[image]

How is this possible? And it has been like this for days, even after reindexing data, so I have no idea.